# Negative lookahead without knowing amount of characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to add a host (myserver.com) to the hosts file under `127.0.0.1`
I'm performing search and replace but I need to match only if the hosts doesn't already exists.

Possible cases are:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain Quality              # Should match because myserver.com isn't here
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain Quality myserver.com # Shouldn't match
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain myserver.com Quality # Shouldn't match
```

I tried negative lookahead but I'm missing something:

```
^127\.0\.0\.1\s+\S*(?!myserver\.com)\S*
```

Comment: Use it like `^(?!.*myserver\.com)127\.0\.0\.1\s+\S*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for all **"127.0.0.1"** in all strings that don't match **"myserver.com"**

`(?!.*myserver\.com.*)(^127\.0\.0\.1.*?$)`

Comment: `^(?!.*myserver\.com)127\.0\.0\.1.*` performs **much** better.